# Path/File Access Error in App.Path

Tags: vb6

Well i made these codes and when i run it the vb6 said me `Path/File Access Error` , can anyone help me:

```
BasePath = App.Path & "\" & "\users\"
MkDir BasePath
Open BasePath & name & "\list.txt" For Input As #1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make `c:\xxx\users\` then open `c:\xxx\users\name\list.txt` but you have not created the `name` sub directory, it wont happen automatically.

You would need to create `\users`, then `\name`. (You should probably also account for the error that will occur if you `mkdir` an existing directory)

**Something like**

```
sub foo
   Dim BasePath As String
   Dim name As String: name = "bob"

   '// get App.Path accounting for "DRIVE:\" which has a trailing \    
   Dim root As String: root = App.Path & IIf(Right$(App.Path, 1) <> "\", "\", "") 

   BasePath = root & "users\"

   makeDir BasePath
   makeDir BasePath & name & "\"

   '//you have this:
   Open BasePath & name & "\list.txt" For Input As #1
   '//but if you have just created the directory, the file wont exist so this will error?
end sub

Sub makeDir(sPath As String)
    If Len(Dir(sPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir sPath
End Sub
```

Comment: so how can i make it , can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

If the directory you're creating already exists you'll get the error you describe on your call to `MkDir`.

I suggest first checking for the existence of the directory before attempting to create it:

```
If (Dir(BasePath, vbDirectory) = "") Then
   MkDir BasePath
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its the `name` variable that's your problem:

For example:

Suppose `Basepath = "C:\Temp\users"` and `name = "FooBar"`

`MKDIR` makes the path for BasePath

The `Open` command will try to create the path at `C:\Temp\Users\FooBar\List.txt`

As you've not created the `FooBar` subdirectory, this is why you get the `File/Path Access Error`

---

Upated with code:

I suspect that your `users` directory will already exist, therefore you need to create the name folder:

```
BasePath = App.Path & "\users\"
MkDir BasePath & name
Open BasePath & name & "\list.txt" For Input As #1
```

Comment: Sry but i confused , can you write me code , beacuse i'm new in this section.